# Android LiveData was observed in three fragments, but only one is actually observing and upadate UI. Other two are not observing

Tags: android, viewmodel, android-livedata

I have tried this problem all days long and still cannot be resolved.

I am writing an app which has three fragments, connected by Navigation Component (with only one activity).

- Fragment A
- Fragment B
- Fragment C

And I observed one LiveData variable from ViewModel in these three fragments.
But only Fragment B is responding. The other two are not.

I have read almost all similar problems from this stack over flow. But still can't see the answer.
Please suggest me.
I have tried removing the observer from FragmentB (which is ok with observing Live Data). But the other two is not still observing)

Here is my code:

Fragment B: (Observe Working)

```
class ServerFragment : Fragment() {

    private lateinit var binding: ServerLayoutBinding
    private val vm: DataModel by viewModels()
   
    private lateinit var devices_observer: Observer<MutableList<ClientSocket>>

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        binding = ServerLayoutBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
        return binding.root

    }


    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)


        var client_list_adapter = ClientListAdapter(layoutInflater)
        binding.clientListRcv.apply {
            layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this.context)
            addItemDecoration(
                DividerItemDecoration(
                    this.context,
                    DividerItemDecoration.VERTICAL
                )
            )
            adapter = client_list_adapter
        }
        client_list_adapter.submitList(vm.clientDevices.value?.toList())


        vm.clientDevices.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {
            client_list_adapter.submitList(vm.clientDevices.value?.toList())} )

}
}
```

Fragment C: (Observe Not Working)

```
class FileListFragment: Fragment() {

    private val vm: DataModel by viewModels()
    private lateinit var binding: FileListBinding

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        binding=FileListBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
        return binding.root
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        //Here I am populating my recycler view with ViewModel data
        //And ViewModel live dat is obeserving here and 
        vm.clientDevices.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer{
               
            ///Here UI updating work will be done. But did'not responded. Here is the problem point I think.
            Toast.makeText(context, "OKKK", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: Post your code first.

Comment: now I edited and added the code. Could you please check?

Comment: Please explain your test scenario. For example, when Fragment C is **visible**, is it responding to new data on `clientDevices`, or is it not?

Comment: Fragment C is Visible. And "clientDevices" is also getting new data ( I made sure by checking in my LogCat). But Fragment C observing "clientDevices" is not responding anything when data update.

Comment: I solved the problem now. I replaced this ViewModel DI "private val vm: DataModel by viewModles() " with "vm= ViewModelProvider(this.requireActivity()).get(DataModel::class.java)" . That solved my problem. Thanks.